# Android PHP Base64 decode with different results

Tags: php, android, base64

I have a big problem : I don't have the same result if I do base64_decode($string); in php or if I do Base64.decode(string); in android.

Example :
with this string : WWhiZWWSZpNlaGSTnpljZQ==

In php, result is Yhbee’f“ehd“ž™ce .

In android, the result is Yhbee�f�ehd���ce

I think there is an encoding problem, but I don't know where, the output of my PHP server is ISO-8859-1, I don't find how to tell to Base64.decode to use this type of encoding.

Can you help me please. Thx for answers.

PS : I can't touch the PHP script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340715/base64-decoding-gives-different-result?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837650/php-base64-encode-doesnt-get-decoded-by-android?rq=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
 Base64.decode(content.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

By this You convert the input String `content` to `ISO-8859-1` encoded byte stream that will be decoded from base64.

Comment: Guys, it is worth to note that Base64.DEFAULT flag will append '\n' at the end of the result. To avoid this behavior, use Base64.NO_WRAP

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you, Don't use `.toString()` use this instead

```
var str = "WWhiZWWSZpNlaGSTnpljZQ=="
var decoded = String(Base64.decode(str, Base64.NO_WRAP))
```

I know this to late to answer :-D

Answer (score 0):

I think the decode is fine, but Android isn't applying the right encoding (probably utf-8).

Does this content appear on an HTML page? If so, are you properly enforcing the `ISO-8859-1` encoding?

Alternatively, you could also switch to UTF-8.