# Android Base64 decode different from javascript and PhP

Tags: android, base64

Sorry for asking this question twice times, but I did research 2 hours...
I have problem with Base64 decode String in my Android.
For example:

- encoded string: `VgFzJ1+TrFa7WsXS5w==`
- The results in javascript and PHP: `Vs'_¬V»ZÅÒç`
- The result in my Android: `Vs'_��V�Z���`

I found a solution from this page [Android PHP Base64 decode with different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705478/android-php-base64-decode-with-different-results)

They say

> By this You convert the input String content to ISO-8859-1 encoded byte stream that will be decoded from base64.

This is my function decoder based on what they say:

```
    byte[] b = Base64.decode(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new String(b, "UTF-8");// event if remove UTF8
```

But still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have resolved by myself

It's very simple to get string from  ISO-8859-1

```
return new String(b, "ISO-8859-1")
```